# Resolving dependencies for Microsoft.Data.Entity.SqlServer fails

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

When resolving the dependencies for `Microsoft.Data.Entity.SqlServer` in a version newer than `0.1-alpha-build-0863`, vs 2014 is not resolving the dependencies for this package. Everything works fine when using the earlier version.

I think some changes in the .nuspec file in the package are to blame for this.

Version `0.1-alpha-build-0863`:

```
<group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5">
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.Common" version="0.1-alpha-build-0137" />
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.Entity" version="0.1-alpha-build-0766" />
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Migrations" version="0.1-alpha-build-0766" />
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational" version="0.1-alpha-build-0766" />
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.SqlServer" version="0.1-alpha-build-0670" />
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection" version="0.1-alpha-build-0362" />
  </group>
```

Version `0.1-alpha-build-1136`:

```
  <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5.1">
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Migrations" version="0.1-alpha-build-1136" />
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.SqlServer" version="0.1-alpha-build-0774" />
  </group>
```

There is a dependency link from `Microsoft.Data.Entity.Migrations` to `Microsoft.Data.Entity`.

**Edit:**

The dependencies are in the packages folder, but they are not detected by vs 2014 ctp and `k build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your project to target .NET 4.5.1, this solved the problem for me. You can do this by updating your project.json file from:

```
"configurations" : {
    "net45" : { },
    "k10" : { }
},
```

To

```
"configurations" : {
    "net451" : { },
    "k10" : { }
},
```